# How do I locate the recursion conditions?

Tags: python, recursion

My code is as follows.

I tried coding out for each case first, so given n = 4, my code looks like this:

```
a = overlay_frac(0,blank_bb,scale(1/4,rune))
b = overlay_frac(1/4,blank_bb,scale(1/2,rune))
c = overlay_frac(1/2,blank_bb,scale(3/4,rune))
d = overlay_frac(3/4,blank_bb,scale(1,rune))
show (overlay(a,(overlay(b,(overlay(c,d))))))
```

My understanding is that the recursion pattern is:

```
a = overlay_frac((1/n)-(1/n),blank_bb,scale(1/n,rune))
b = overlay_frac((2/n)-(1/n),blank_bb,scale(2/n,rune))
c = overlay_frac((3/n)-(1/n),blank_bb,scale(3/n,rune))
d = overlay_frac((4/n)-(1/n),blank_bb,sale(4/n,rune))
```

Hence, the recursion pattern that I came up with is:

```
def tree(n,rune):
    if n==1:
        return rune
    else:
        for i in range(n+1):
            return overlay(overlay_frac(1-(1/n),blank_bb,scale(i/n,rune)),tree(n-1,rune))
```

When I hardcode this, everything turns out just fine, but I suspect I'm not doing the recursion properly. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: `return` exits a function immediately; your `for` loop is not going to reach the next iteration.

Comment: that is only for n ==1, right? If I call for tree(n>1,rune), it should still reach the next iteration.

Comment: No, it won’t. The function has already exited.

Comment: Perhaps my understanding of recursion is not very good, because after trying out the code, you're right. It only shows as though n=1. Could you please give me some pointers on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Besides that, the value you pass for the first argument in recursion is often not an integer, yet you treat it as one in the function, and the recursion will risk to never hit the end condition (1) and thus fall into a stack overflow exception. Maybe you should explain what you want to calculate.

Comment: Could you explain in English what your desired result is? I suspect the code for `overlay_frac`, `blank_bb`, and `sale` might help too.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `overlay_frac`, `blank_bb` and `scale` are already functions provided beforehand. But `overlay_frac` takes in 3 arguments (a fraction of the top layer, pattern1, pattern2). `blank_bb` is just a blank sheet to help with the coding. `scale` is to scale down the shape of the original rune. So what I am aiming for is actually 4 circles (almost like a dartboard), with the middle circle the darkest and the circle fading as it spreads out.

Comment: your recursion pattern is off. for example, in a, if 1/n=1/4 i.e. n=4 then 1-1/4 is not zero

Comment: My apologies, just fixed the code

Comment: @statsguy21: this is not a recursion problem, though; `return` will exit a function, however it was called or whatever other function it calls to. You'll need to find a way to solve your problem without using an unconditional `return` in a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are in fact trying to do an iteration within a recursive call. In stead of using loop, you can use an inner function to memorize your status. The coefficient you defined is actually changed with both `n` and `i`, but for a given `n` it changed with `i` only. The status you need to memorize with inner function is then `i`, which is the same as you looping through `i`.

You can still achieve your goal by doing so

```
def f(i, n): 
  return overlay_frac((i/n)-(1/n),blank_bb,scale(i/n,rune))

# for each iteration, you check if i is equal to n
# if yes, return the result (base case)
# otherwise, you apply next coefficient to the previous result
# you start with i = 0 and increase by one every iteration until i reach to n (base case)
# notice how similar this recursive call looks like a loop
# the only difference is the status are updated within the function call itself
# therefore you will not have the problem of earlier return 
def recursion(n):
  def iteration(i, out):
    if i == n:
      return out
    else:
      return iteration(i+1, overlay(f(n-1, n), out))
  return iteration(0, f(n, n))
```

Here, `n` is assumed to be the times of overlay you want to apply. When `n = 0`, no function applied on the last coefficient `f(n, n)`. When `n = 1`, the output would be overlay applied once on coefficient with `i = n - 1` and coefficient with `i = n`.

This way avoids the earlier return inside your loop.

In fact you can omit the inner function by adding additional argument to your outer function. Then you need to assign the default initial `i`. The inner function is not really necessary here. The key is to use the function argument to memorize the status (variable `i` in this case).

```
def f(i, n): 
  return overlay_frac((i/n)-(1/n),blank_bb,scale(i/n,rune))

def recursion(n, i=0):
    if i == n:
      return f(n, n)
    else:
      return overlay(f(n-1, n), recursion(n, i+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first two code blocks don't correspond to the same operations. This would be equivalent to your first block (in Python 3).

```
def overlayer(n, rune):
    def layer(k):
        # Scale decreases linearly with k
        return overlay_frac((1 - (k+1)/n), blank_bb, scale(1-k/n, rune))
    result = layer(0)
    for i in range(1, n):
        # Overlay on top of previous layers
        result = overlay(layer(i), result)
    return result

show(overlayer(4, rune))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at your equations again:

```
a = overlay_frac(0,blank_bb,scale(1/4,rune))
b = overlay_frac(1/4,blank_bb,scale(1/2,rune))
c = overlay_frac(1/2,blank_bb,scale(3/4,rune))
d = overlay_frac(3/4,blank_bb,scale(1,rune))
show (overlay(a,(overlay(b,(overlay(c,d))))))
```

What you wrote as "recursion" is not a recursion formula. If you compare your formulas for the recursion with the ones you gave us, you can infer `n=4` which makes no sense. For a recursion pattern you need to describe your inner variables as a manifestation of the same expression with only a different parameter. That is, you should replace:

```
f_n = overlay_frac((1/4)*(n-1),blank_bb,sale(n/4,rune))
```

such that `f_1=a, f_2=b` etc...

Then your recursion fomula that you want to calculate translates to:

```
show (overlay(f_1,(overlay(f_2,(overlay(f_3,f_4))))))
```

You can write the function `f_n` as `f(n)` (and maybe other paramters) in your code and then do

```
def recurse(n):
    if n == 4:
        return f(4)
    else:
        return overlay(f(n),recurse(n+1))
```

then call:

```
show( recurse (1))
```

You need to assert that `n<5`and integer, otherwise you'll end up in an infinity loop.
There may still be some mistake, but it should be along those lines. Once you've actually written it like this however, it (maybe) doesn't really make sense to do a recursion anyways. If you only want to do it for `n_max=4`, that is. Just call the function in one line by replacing `a,b,c,d` with `f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4`